# Inline Jquery Works but External file is not working properly

Tags: jquery, animation, scrolltop

I am fairly new to jquery

The Code

Html

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="Jq/jquery.Lines.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Pageworth of content</p>
           <div class="aLine"></div>
    </body>
```

css

```
.aLine{
    height: 40%;
    width: 20px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#00FFE5;



}
.aLine.active{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00FFE5;
    transition: height 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: aLine 1s ease-out forwards;
       -moz-animation: aLine 1s ease-out forwards;
        -ms-animation: aLine 1s ease-out forwards;
         -o-animation: aLine 1s ease-out forwards;
            animation: aLine 1s ease-out forwards;

}
```

Jquery

```
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}
// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.aLine');

    // If the animation has already been started


    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation

        $elem.addClass('active');


    }

   else{
        $elem.removeClass('active');


    }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
});
```

Now the script works if I include it in the html but that ends up being incredibly bulky. And for some reason as an external file it just doesn't do anything. I fell like i'm not linking something, but i'm not entirely sure.

I've tried adding

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
    checkAnimation();
    isElementInViewport(elem);
  });
    </script>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.aLine')checkAnimation();

        });
    </script>
```

To both the header and just before the closing body tag, but neither of which has worked. I'm pretty new to jquery so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First check if there is any console errors in your browser may be like your external jquery file might not be properly referred. Next try adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="...">`

Comment: Yep that was it I misspelled the name of the script :/. Thank you so much!